# I am using node js to insert values from html file to sql server but it shows values as undefined under SQL server Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

After fill information in below WebForm and submit my data ,I got undefined values under ms sql server records.

//my html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Employees</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

   
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><center>Add a new Employee</center></h1><br>

    <center>
      <form action = "http://localhost:8080/api" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type ="text" name ="first_Name" placeholder="Enter First Name"><br>
         <br>
         <input type ="text" name = "last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name"><br>
        
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
      </form><br>
    </center>

    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <script src="Node.js"></script>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my Node.js code :

```
//Initiallising node modules
var express = require('express');
var bodyPasrser = require('body-parser');
var sql = require('mssql');
var app = express();


//Body Parser to parse to JSON
app.use(bodyPasrser.json());


//CORS Middleware
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin,X-Requested-With,contentType,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization");
    next();
});


//Setting up server
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT||8080,function(){
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port ",port);
});


//setup database connection



var dbconfig = {
    user:"sa",
    password:"--------",
    server : "localhost",
    database: "Test"  
};


// ConnectionPool


//connect to the database 
var executeQuery = function(res,query){
    sql.connect(dbconfig,function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("there is a database connection error -> "+err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else{
            // create request object
            var request = new sql.Request();
            // query to the database
            request.query(query,function(err,result){
                if(err){
                    console.log("error while querying database -> "+err);
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else{
                    res.send(result);
                    sql.close();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}


// Change execute query to accept parameters.
var executeQuery = function(res,query,parameters){
    sql.connect(dbconfig,function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("there is a database connection error -> "+err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else{
            // create request object
            var request = new sql.Request();

            // Add parameters
            parameters.forEach(function(p) {
                request.input(p.name, p.sqltype, p.value);
            });

            // query to the database
            request.query(query,function(err,result){
                if(err){
                    console.log("error while querying database -> "+err);
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else{
                    res.send(result);
                    sql.close();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}



//POST API
app.post("/api", function(req , res){

    var parameters = [
      { name: 'First_Name', sqltype: sql.NVarChar, value: req.body.First_Name},
      { name: 'Last_name', sqltype: sql.NVarChar,  value: req.body.Last_name},
    ];

        var query = "INSERT INTO test.dbo.name (First_Name,Last_name) VALUES ('" +req.body.First_Name+"','"+req.body.Last_name+"')";
    executeQuery (res, query, parameters);
});
```

After display the records under SQL server I found that data I submitted , as  "undefined" and it is not my data I submitted in the webform , please what is wrong in my code.

Please can give simple example in how to solve such case

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There is typo in form data you are using,

```
var query = "INSERT INTO test.dbo.name (First_Name,Last_name) VALUES ('" +req.body.First_Name+"','"+req.body.Last_name+"')";
```

should be,

```
var query = "INSERT INTO test.dbo.name (First_Name,Last_name) VALUES ('" +req.body.first_Name +"','"+req.body.last_name+"')";
```

Comment: I done the changes based on your shared comments, but still the issue is the same .

Comment: what do you see in logs when post api is called, check out the req param in log. app.post("/api", function(req , res){